# AWS Glue Schema Registry Imports

Tags: amazon-web-services, avro, aws-glue

When generating Java classes from Avro Schemas through `avro-maven-plugin`, I am able to import custom types for reuse across schemas.

`shared/child_type.avsc`

```
{
  "namespace": "my.namespace",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ChildType",
  "fields": [ ... ]
}
```

`parent_type.avsc`. See `field_of_custom_type` field.

```
{
  "namespace": "my.namespace",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ParentType",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "field_of_custom_type",
      "type": "my.namespace.ChildType"
    }
  ]
}
```

`pom.xml`. See imports section.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${avro.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${avro.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    <imports>
                        <import>${avro.sourceDirectory}/shared</import>
                    </imports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

It is my understanding that this is supported in the Confluent Schema Registry (https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/523) too.

**Is this also possible in the AWS Glue Schema registry?**

Relevant error message:

> InvalidInputException: Schema definition is invalid: "my.namespace.ChildType" is not a defined name. The type of the "field_of_custom_type" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression.

Comment: I suggest using `avdl` files instead, which approriately expand the nested types when the final avsc schema files are created

Comment: Hey Sigoy, did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue referencing a schema from another schema.

Comment: @davidmerrick as the above commenter suggested, I ended up writing avdl files with proper imports and adding a build step to generate the avsc files (avro-tools idl2schemata if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Thanks, @Sigoy! So you must be essentially embedding the schema instead of importing it? I was also trying to determine if imports worked in the Glue Schema Registry with Avro, and they don't appear to be.

Comment: Yup, the build step embedds the nested types, but they do serialize/deserialize to the correct (generated) Java classes which was what I was after in this particular project. I never got imports to work with this registry.